# Symfony2 Doctrine Query Entity Error

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would use a field in a query but i receive this error:
**[Semantical Error] line 0, col 78 near 'resource_id =': Error: Class Dt\TagBundle\Entity\Tagging has no field or association named resource_id**

This is my entity Tagging:

```
<?php

 namespace Dt\TagBundle\Entity;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;
 use FPN\TagBundle\Entity\Tagging as BaseTagging;


 /**
  * Dt\TagBundle\Entity\Tagging
  *
  * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="tagging_idx",      columns={"tag_id", "resource_type", "resource_id"})})
  * @ORM\Entity
  */
 class Tagging extends BaseTagging
 {
/**
 * @var integer $id
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Dt\TagBundle\Entity\Tag")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $tag;
 }
```

The table on my db is: Tagging(id, tag_id, resource_type, resource_id)
where **tag_id** correspond at the id of the table: Tag(id,name) 
and **resource_id** correspond at the User table User(id, name , surname, ...)

This is my search query:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
         ->select('uu')   
         ->from('DtEcBundle:User', 'uu')
         ->innerJoin("DtTagBundle:Tag","tg", "WITH", "tg.id = tig.tag")
         ->innerJoin("DtTagBundle:Tagging","tig", "WITH", "tig.resource_id = uu.id")
         ->innerJoin("DtTagBundle:Tag","tg", "WITH", "tg.id = tig.tag") 
         ->where("uu.surname LIKE :search OR uu.name LIKE :search OR uu.profession LIKE :search OR tg.name LIKE :search")
         ->setParameter("search",$search.'%')
            ->getQuery();
```

How can i do to define resource_id??? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code for the base class for your entity, you will find that the field is called `resourceId` not `resource_id`. It is saved in the `resource_id` column in the database but that is not what you need to use in Doctrine queries. So, you should change it to:

```
     ->innerJoin("DtTagBundle:Tagging","tig", "WITH", "tig.resourceId = uu.id")
```

Comment: Thanks, now work!!!! Why resourceId and not resource_id?? Can you explain, please? @Carlos Granados

Comment: I explained it in the answer: in doctrine queries you need to use the name of the fields, not the name of the database columns where they are saved